# How to Enable button in To Do task in infopath

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

How Can I Enable the Button in To-do Task, Only After changing the already existing data in the date field of info path. Still modifying the old date button in To-do task need to be in disable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple just i have add another one Field in infopath form and while clicking submit button it will set field value of old data into the new field and then compare the present data with old data in new field so that we can enable the complete button with this rules.